# Loading external .js with jQuery 1.5.1

Tags: jquery

I have been using this piece of script to load external .js files to the document:

```
$.ajax({
    url: dir + '/' + module + '.js',
    dataType: 'script',
    async: false,
    success: function() {
        modules[module].init();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert('Error loading module "' + module + '"');
    }
});
```

But when I switch to jQuery 1.5.1 (instead of 1.4.2 I was using before) it stops working. It loads the file but not as a success - file contents gets passed as errors xhr.responseText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the 'complete' event from $.ajax() instead of the 'success' event?

---

If you need to dynamically load a javascript source file, you can append the [script] tag to the [head] tag:

```
$("head").append(
  unescape('%3Cscript src="/path/to/javascript.js"%3E%3C/script%3E');
);
```

The only problem with that, is you must prevent the script from getting loaded more than once.

I like to have an if() condition which tests for the presence of a function that I know is defined in the dynamically loaded javascript file.  I use underscore.js and _.isFunction() to test for this ( http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isFunction ).  Only load the javascript src file if the test function isn't defined:

```
if( !( _.isFunction(someTestFunction) ) ) {
  $("head").append(
    unescape('%3Cscript src="/path/to/javascript.js"%3E%3C/script%3E');
  );
}
```

Comment: I could possibly do something like that, but what really interests me is why doesn't the script that worked fine in jquery 1.4.2 work in v1.5.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/[name of script].js"></script>
```

You just need to make sure that you include the jQuery file before defining any functions using it.

Comment: That's not what I asked for; the system must be able to load and launch modules dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, it seems like your code has some scoping issues. Without seeing in what context it is used it's hard to tell exactly what's wrong, but most likely because the variable `module` is not defined in your `success` & `error` callback. So I think you should check if `module` is defined in those two callbacks.

Also, you can save yourself sometime and use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead.

Comment: Scoping? :) It does not even trigger "success", it goes directly to  "error", so any scopes shouldn't be the cause here. I should probably add, that it loads scripts from a .jar archive .. but as I mentioned earlier, it worked fine in jQuery v1.4.2